# Value initialization of inherited POD types

Tags: c++

Suppose the following:

```
struct POD1 { int a; };
struct POD2 : POD1 { int b; };

int main() {
    POD2 p2 = POD2();
    return 0;
}
```

Will both `p2.a` and `p2.b` equal 0 after `p2` is defined? Basically I'm not sure if the value initialization rules also apply to base classes of POD types.

Comment: @jrok: Thanks, I've corrected my code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>POD2 p2();</strike>

That does not do what you expect, but rather declares a function by the name `p2` that takes no argument and returns a `POD2`.

Now, a slightly different case would be:

```
POD2 p2 = POD2();
```

The right hand side of the expression `POD2()` represents the creation of a temporary that is *value-initialized* [5.2.3/2]. *Value-initialization* for a user defined type with no user defined constructor is *zero-initialization* [8.5/7], and *zero-initialization* of that type will *zero-initialize* each one of the members and bases [8.5/5] guaranteeing that both members are 0.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't compile the code (obviously) so I apologize for the oversight in my p2 definition. I've corrected my OP.

Comment: @JohnB: `POD2 p2;` does what is expected, i.e. does not initialize the members and as such it cannot be preferred over `POD2 p2 = POD2();` that does guarantee the initialization, they are different things, and you use one or the other depending on what you need.